# Why is my get_token() not the same as my request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE")?

Tags: python, html, django, angular, typescript

Does anyone know why I am encountering this issue?

I'm starting to test Angular 17 as a FrontEnd with Django as a Backend, and when validating a form, I encounter the issue that when obtaining my token from Django and sending it in the HTTP header, it doesn't match the token expected by Django. I'm not sure if the problem is that the expected token is not updating with **`get_token()`** or if **`get_token()`** is returning the incorrect token.

settings.py:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:4200",
    ]
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'XSRF-TOKEN'
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
#En esta sección configuro el CORS

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:4200",
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:4200",  # Angular
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    'x-requested-with',
    'Content-Type',
    '_HttpHeaders',
]
```

csrf-service.service.ts

```
export class CsrfService {
  private csrfToken: string | null = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  //Obtener el token CSRF
  getCsrfToken(): string | null {
    return this.csrfToken;
  }

  //Cargar el token CSRF desde el servidor
  loadCsrfToken(): Observable<any> {
    const csrfUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/obt_csrf_token/';
    return this.http.get<any>(csrfUrl);
  }

  //Actualizar el token CSRF en el servicio
  updateCsrfToken(): void {
    this.loadCsrfToken().subscribe(
      (token: any) => {
        this.csrfToken = token.csrf_token;
        console.log("Token actualizado: ", this.csrfToken)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error al obtener el token CSRF:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I'll also provide part of my console output so you can see how the expected token and the generated token look when loading the login page and when clicking the login button, respectively.

`CSRF Token del Header: None`

`Token generado en Django:  uG6NSwsHnBNXlzE9j6iEwptSJL5u7QUtswINXYSicBa6HLV0Rv4gl09TlhHCTDB9`

`CSRF Token esperado:::::::: 80MafCALZaxjwmr1IzWMZLQbMGMiWXRQ`

`CSRF Token Mismatch!`

`[30/Jan/2024 13:23:47] "GET /obt_csrf_token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 82`

clicking login button:

`CSRF Token del Header: U8gtsYhx3PRa6myG9QAB5PhjlxZTJRmmSYStxqH8SPejsyPxHfmdUqXkX3B1vE32`

`Token generado en Django:  9emhI1IdTIkWDkQPU4fC7xs6fbSIu64e9OUjB8NiAsjG4v4MkUIQOa9EZxkkCAxL`

`CSRF Token esperado:::::::: aKIc3hffRU9UBlo7A0DoRNRIUwCMiEDH`

`CSRF Token Mismatch!`

`Forbidden (CSRF token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP header incorrect.): /procesar_iniciar_sesion/`

`[30/Jan/2024 13:24:04] "POST /procesar_iniciar_sesion/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2552`

I would appreciate any help you can provide :)

I have tried using **`{% csrf_token %}`** in the form, but it's not possible to use it in an Angular 17 form. I also attempted to call **`request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE")`** instead of the **`get_token()`** function, but it returned an undefined token. I used **`csrf_exempt`**, and it worked, but I am aware that it poses a security risk for the page as it essentially 'disables' the use of tokens, which is not what I am looking for.

My hope is to achieve consistency between both **`get_token()`** and the expected token in Django without the need to use **`csrf_exempt`**."

Comment: you should use CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = FALSE  And then use Angular's  HttpClientXsrfModule.  See this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813863/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-have-csrf-protection-in-a-django-rest-framework  Angular's bit will read that cookie which is set on each response by the backend.  Angular will then send it as a custom header which your backend reads and validates.  (this happens automatically on every non-simple request so it's a lot less work than you are doing now... just be sure to use relative paths or the module won't send it)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.
I don't know if it's something related to Angular 17, but it doesn't let me modify the HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions Therefore, I left its values as default (cookieName=XSRF-TOKEN and headerName=X-XSRF-TOKEN), and I modified the settings to: CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'XSRF-TOKEN' and CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'. Is what I did correct?
Regarding relative paths, I think you mean using 'http://localhost:8000'. If that's the case, I'm not very clear yet on how to make it relative, considering that they are in different origins (Django backend.

Comment: My header ends up as "Xsrf-Token"... even though I've set HttpClientXsrfModule options to "XSRF-TOKEN"... ends up camel-cased for some reason.  Not sure about the "http_" part, but default should be "X-Xsrf-Token". If you use "environment" files, you'd set baseURL to relative.. just "." If you need to set a port for local debugging, you'd configure the backend to not check the CSRF token. (check Django docs for that... you'll bypass CSRF checks globally when in development)  You should setup a way to test locally where domain is same just so you can verify tokens in dev-tools.

Comment: I do that by putting the ng build output in with the debug server build.  It's a pain to test... since you'll be turning on/off global CSRF checks/baseURLs a bit until you test it well enough to know it's working.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. When I'm developing locally with different origins for the backend and frontend, is it better to avoid CSRF token checking, either with csrf_exempt or some other type of "blocking"? And if I want to test the token, should I set up a local test where the domains are the same?

Comment: right... hopefully Django has a global setting for checking CSRF token.  In ASP.NET I do something like: if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{ ... turn off CSRF checking } else { ...turn it on }  For local testing I add the angular build to the development build so it's same domain and switch environment to use "." baseURL and switch server to turn on CSRF checks for development.   Then I can check the requests in Chrome's dev tools to check requests and responses.

Comment: If you want to use absolute paths, you need to write your own version of HttpClientXsrfModule...   it excludes absolute paths.  (probably for security, but not sure exactly why that is...)  Btw, you shouldn't need to set "CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN" that would be set automatically to the current domain by the browser.  The cookie will be set to a different value for each request which is why your endpoint method does not work.  (That's not tied to the form's anti-csrf value... which is usually another cookie that is checked against the CSRF token you're sending in header)

Comment: I've been looking into having the backend and frontend on the same domain locally, and I saw that you can use 'ng serve --port 8000' to have both ports set to 8000. When I wake up, I'll try to look into the issue of relative paths more thoroughly, and I'll keep you posted on any updates.

Comment: Well, I'm here to give an update on how I solved my problem. When using Angular and Django, it is recommended to use tokens in cookies, so do not use get_token(). Instead, get the token from the cookie and then compare them by sending the token in the header of the HTTP request. I still don't know if this can be insecure, but from what I've researched, it's not :), i hope my solution serves as a solution for you all, thanks to Browsermator for helping me <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm here to give an update on how I solved my problem. When using Angular and Django, it is recommended to use tokens in cookies, so do not use get_token(). Instead, get the token from the cookie and then compare them by sending the token in the header of the HTTP request. I still don't know if this can be insecure, but from what I've researched, it's not :), i hope my solution serves as a solution for you all.

The python code to use for return the xsrf-token cookie value in your python view:

```
#if u token dont generate use get_token(request) first and then this line 
xsrf_token_value = request.COOKIES.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
```